# Как вывести картинку из базы данных mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток!
Натягиваю верстку на WP и нужно вывести картинки из бд в слайдер.

- создал таблицу
- подключился к бд
- написал вывод данных в цикле

  ```
      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
      $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
      $connectedDe = mysql_select_db('wptest');
      mysql_set_charset('utf8');
      $limit = 4;
      if(!$connection || $connectedDe){
          mysql_error();
      }

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimonials");
      mysql_close();
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  ```

Все выводится, кроме картинок. Вместо картинки выводится бинарный код. Практически наверняка дело в кодировке но я не могу понять в чем ошибка.

Картинки вывожу так

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="client photo before training" class="feedback-img_left" id="feedback-img_left">
```

На странице выводится бинарный код картинки и ошибка:

> : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\wptest\wp-content\themes\personal_trainer\header.php:4) in on line

На 4й строке я подключаю title страницы стандартно.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Спасибо!

Comment: Как хранится картинка в базе - ссылка на неё(путь?) или сырой файл в двоичном виде(ужас)?

Comment: А есть какая-то причина, которая мешает использовать для этого стандартные средства Wordpress?

Comment: @АндрейАршинов Хранится сырым файлом, я так понимаю лучше сохранить в таблице путь или название файла который хранится где то отдельно на сервере и в коде вызывать именно этот путь?

Comment: @labris Общая логика такая:
через форму можно добавить отзыв и прикрепить картинку - и это все сходу должно отобразиться в кастомном слайдере.

Comment: @Oslo безусловно так будет лучше и правильнее.

Comment: @АндрейАршинов Спасибо большое за совет, попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в базе данных хранить путь к картинке

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "");
$connectedDe = mysql_select_db('test');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

if( ! $connection || $connectedDe)
{
    mysql_error();
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `testimonials`");
mysql_close();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo "<img src='" . $row['image'] . "' alt='' />";
}
```